# Copy from a DataGridView to an Excel sheet and keeping sheet formatting

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, interop

I can copy/paste fine from my DGV to Excel but my Grid formatting is exported to Excel while I'd like to keep my cells as they are configured.

Here's how I do it :

```
private void copyDGV()
{
    dataGridViewOrdre.SelectAll();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewOrdre.Rows)
    {
        if (row.IsNewRow)
        {
            row.Selected = false;
        }
    }

    DataObject dataObj = dataGridViewOrdre.GetClipboardContent();
    if (dataObj != null)
    {
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
    }

    dataGridViewOrdre.ClearSelection();
}

private void buttonExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string nouveauFichier = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\Bon de Livraison " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MM yyyy HH-mm-ss") + ".xlsx";
    File.Copy(modele, nouveauFichier);
    copyDGV();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlexcel;
    Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    xlexcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    xlexcel.Visible = true;
    xlWorkBook = xlexcel.Workbooks.Open(nouveauFichier);
    xlWorkSheet = (Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
    Range CR = (Range)xlWorkSheet.Cells[29, 1];
    CR.Select();
    xlWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(Type.Missing, false, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Using something like `xlWorkSheet.Cells[29, 1].Value = dataGridViewOrdre.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value;` keeps my Excel sheet formatting. Is it the actual way to do it instead of a copy/paste ?

Comment: I do not think the command `xlWorkSheet.Cells[29, 1].Value =` is correct. Try removing the `Value` property. I do not think Excel has that property and the corrected line `xlWorkSheet.Cells[29, 1] = dataGridViewOrdre.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value;` should work as you describe.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird because I get it to work with or without the Value property. I remember actually adding it yesterday after I got an Exception raised and adding the Value property fixed it.

Comment: Then what is the issue? It is unclear how the copy paste is coming into play if you know what cells you want to put in the excel file.

Comment: @JohnG I thought that a raw copy/paste would be more elegant and less error prone than a for loop and adding manually values to my sheet.

Comment: I am not really sure how “elegant” either approach is. However, IMHO the copy paste is more error prone and if I am not mistaken, reverting to using the “windoze” OS copy/paste as the code appears to do from a grid, will NOT copy empty cells. Meaning that if there are empty cells “selected” and you issue `Ctrl-C`… when you “paste” the cells into Excel it will mess up the column and or row placement of the cells in relation to how the cells are located in the grid. I could be mistaken about this; however, I would check it before you jump down that rabbit hole.